# Apply Patch Update

Tags: wix, windows-installer, inno-setup

We are the product development company. We have the MSI setup for product it will install the more than 500 assemblies files in customers machine.
Once we had released the product there may be some problem in any our of the assemblies due to several reasons. 
At the time we will fix those problem and provided the patch update to the customer.

[b]Current System:[/b]

1) Fix the problem in the devlopement environment and build the assemblies.

2) Generate the Patch setup using the Inno script with modified assemblies.

3) While installing the patch setup in the customer machine it will backup the old assemblies and replace the modified assemblies.

[b]Drawback:[/b]

Customer can't able to uninstall the installed patch becoz it just replace the assemblies.

Is it possible to have the patch system in MSI like MSP files or else is there any option to uninstall the patch in my current system itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer supports uninstallable patches starting from version 3.0. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372102.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372104.aspx) for more details. [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net) supports uninstallable patches via AllowRemoval attribute of [Patch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_patch.htm) element.

Comment: Except InnoSetup isn't MSI based.